# unittest fails on import--missing symbols

Tags: python, pydev

Am new to Python, Python command line and PyDev. Fedora 20, Python 2.7.5 as it came on this distro. I am unable to write a unit test. Have tried importing unittest and unittest2 (as here).

```
from unittest2 import TestCase, main

def IsOdd( n ):
    return n % 2 == 1

class IsOddTests( TestCase ):
    def testOne( self ):
        self.failUnless( IsOdd( 1 ) )
    def testTwo( self ):
        self.failIf( IsOdd( 2 ) )

def main():
    main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Each import has its problems. This happens whether from PyDev console in Eclipse or at the command line shell. I have looked at what's under /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/* and I find the missing symbols (TestCase and unit), but this isn't helpful to present case.

```
/usr/bin/python 2.7.5 (default, Nov  3 2014, 14:26:24) 
[GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-7)]
PyDev console: starting.
>>> from unittest2 import TestCase, main
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unittest2/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from unittest2.collector import collector
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unittest2/collector.py", line 3, in <module>
    from unittest2.loader import defaultTestLoader
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unittest2/loader.py", line 8, in <module>
    import unittest
  File "/home/russ/dev/python-workspace/max/src/unittest.py", line 11, in <module>
    from unittest2 import TestCase, main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unittest2/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from unittest2 import loader, runner
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unittest2/runner.py", line 7, in <module>
    from unittest2 import result
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unittest2/result.py", line 26, in <module>
    class TestResult(unittest.TestResult):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TestResult'
>>> from unittest import TestCase, main
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/russ/dev/python-workspace/max/src/unittest.py", line 11, in <module>
    from unittest2 import TestCase, main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unittest2/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from unittest2.collector import collector
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unittest2/collector.py", line 3, in <module>
    from unittest2.loader import defaultTestLoader
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unittest2/loader.py", line 12, in <module>
    from unittest2 import case, suite
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unittest2/case.py", line 10, in <module>
    from unittest2 import result
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unittest2/result.py", line 9, in <module>
    from unittest2 import util
ImportError: cannot import name util
```

Comment: If you're new to python then use python 3 if you can. `unittest2` *is* the `unittest` package in python 3.

Comment: Thanks, however, my work will be necessarily in python 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used unittest2. It seems like using plain unittest might be a bit better for your situation given that its a python builtin and is well vetted. I was able to get this to work for me

```
from unittest import TestCase, main as unittest_main

def IsOdd( n ):
    return n % 2 == 1

class IsOddTests( TestCase ):
    def testOne( self ):
        self.failUnless( IsOdd( 1 ) )
    def testTwo( self ):
        self.failIf( IsOdd( 2 ) )

def main():
    unittest_main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then running it

```
0 ✓ greg@MinasArnor ~/workspace $ python test.py 
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

OK
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get: (a whole trace ending in)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TestResult'

Comment: then it sounds like something is wrong with your python environment rather than unittest

Comment: This is what worked on my Mint 17 host at home; it still does not work on Fedora 20 at my employment.

Comment: I wiped Eclipse and associated subdirectories utterly from my Fedora 20 host where this wasn't working. I reinstalled Luna IDE for Java EE Developers from scratch including PyDev and redid this example (calling it demo.py) and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this in your back trace:

```
File "/home/russ/dev/python-workspace/max/src/unittest.py", line 11, in <module>
```

and this:

```
class TestResult(unittest.TestResult):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TestResult'
```

Rename your file. You've named your script `unittest.py`, so Python is looking at **your** unittest script for classes (like TestResult) and not the builtin unittest module like it's supposed to.

Comment: I was following a tutorial on-line. It wasn't my code. Nevertheless, this code here still errors out in PyDev and on the command line ultimately with AttributeError: 'module' object has not attribute 'TestResult'

Comment: hmmm strange. It may be a dependency issue, maybe try reinstalling unittest2 and if that fails then try doing another reinstall but with the `--verbose` flag.

Comment: Okay I know your problem. Rename your file to something besides `unittest.py` I think that will cure all your issues.

Comment: Yes, I now choose demo.py. It still doesn't work on Fedora 20 with new installation of Eclipse Luna and PyDev. I must have inadvertantly broken something.